# Camel...Evaluating a java expression

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a camel flow which routes from an activemq to another activemq. However, I need to evaluate an expression and set it as a header. How do I achieve that.

```
<from uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq1"/>
    <setHeader headerName="EVENT_KEY">
         <simple>${java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()}</simple>
    </setHeader>
 <to uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq2"/>
```

But the header is not being set correctly?
How do I set `java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()` value to the header?
pls advise

Comment: Although I have already answered your question, I might add  this particular usecase - to create some unique key for a particular transaction/event is very common. Camel already does this by default. Look at the breadcrumbId header, which is essentially the same thing as your EVENT_KEY header. http://camel.apache.org/mdc-logging.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Groovy expression](http://camel.apache.org/groovy.html) language for that. The simple language is ok for concatenating strings and comparing parts of the payload, but for more logic, groovy is a swiss army knife.

```
<from uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq1"/>
    <setHeader headerName="EVENT_KEY">
         <groovy>java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()</groovy>
    </setHeader>
 <to uri="jms:queue:Q.activemq2"/>
```

You need to add a dependency to camel-groovy to make it work.